# Creating a new entity and using magical record I lose autocomplete

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, magicalrecord

I have an existing project that I am using magical record with.  I create a new entity, with 2 string attributes, and I can no longer reference any of the core data classes.  I created the entity, I ran the mogenerator, and I updated my entity file that lists all the core data header files.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I didn't do the initial implementation of this project and I am trying to figure this out as I go along.

Comment: When I say reference I mean autocompletion is not working and if I reference the objects anyways project is not compiling.